# Parameter of an URL within another URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, google-feed-api

This is a simple to understand question, I will explain step by step as to make everything clear.

I am using the Google Feed API to load an RSS file into my JavaScript application.

I have a setting to bypass the Google cache, if needed, and I do this by appending a random number at the end of the RSS file link that I send to the Google Feed API.

For example, let's say this is a link to an RSS:

```
http://example.com/feed.xml
```

To bypass the cache, I append a random number at the end as a parameter:

```
http://example.com/feed.xml?0.12345
```

The whole url to the Google Feed API would look like this, where "q" is the above link:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&q=http://example.com/feed.xml?0.12345
```

This bypasses the cache and works well in most cases but there is a problem when the RSS link that I want to use already has parameters. For example, like this:

```
http://example.com/feed?type=rss
```

Appending the number at the end like before would give an error and the RSS file would not be returned:

```
http://example.com/feed?type=rss?0.12345 // ERROR
```

I have tried using "&" to attach the random number, as so:

```
http://example.com/feed?type=rss&0.12345
```

This no longer gives an error and the RSS file is correctly returned. But if I use the above in the Google Feed API url, it no longer bypasses the cache:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&q=http://example.com/feed.xml&0.1234
```

This is because "0.1234" is considered a parameter of the whole url and not a parameter of the "q" url. Therefore "q" remains only as "http://example.com/feed.xml", it is not unique so the cached version is loaded.

Is there a way to make the number parameter be a part of the "q" url and not a part of the whole url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` like this:

```js
var url = 'http://example.com/feed.xml&0.1234';
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

You are escaping the special characters that would have been treated as part of the url otherwise.

To append or create a queryString:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/feed.xml';
var randomParameter = '0.1234';
var queryString = url.indexOf('?') > - 1;
if(queryString){
    url = url + '&' + randomParameter;
} else {
    url = url + '?' + randomParameter;
}
//url needs to be escaped with encodeURIComponent;
```

Comment: I will remember the point about escaping the special characters, it makes sense.

Comment: There is a problem with this. Appending the "&0.1234" at the end of the url  gives a "not found" error and the RSS file is not returned. If I use  "?0.1234", I encounter the problem in the original post, when the url already has "?".

Comment: You should check out the final url being used, unless google does something weird with your query string which makes no sense to me. I highly doubt the problem is with the URL to be honest. Could you provide the real URL?

Comment: Here is a real url, first without the number then with it attached at the end: http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml , http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml&0.12345

Comment: You are butchering the url since there's no `queryString`. In other words, that's a different url from `news/rss.xml`. Whatever you append to your URL must be part of your `queryString`(?key=value) which goes **after** the url.

Comment: Wasn't your example above exactly like that? Did I miss something? And I have mentioned in the original post and above that appending "?0.12345" encounters a problem when my url already has a queryString, as the following real url: http://www.fecareers.co.uk/jobboard/xmlfeeds/jobfeed.asp?type=RSS . The only way that I can think of is to search the url string and make a fork in the code - append the random number with "&" if there is a queryString, append it with "?" if there is none.

Comment: I was under the impression that you'd handle that case through your server, but since it's not your server it makes a lot more sense to me. You need to check if the `queryString` exists (check for `?`) and if it exists, append the `key=value` pair at the end of it. Otherwise create one.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use encodeURIComponent to do this.

```
encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/feed.xml&0.1234')
```

will result in

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffeed.xml%260.1234
```

and when appended to the end result you'll get

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&q=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffeed.xml%260.1234
```